# Test-Path and PATH environment variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have some code that uses `Start-Process` and `-FilePath` can be either a fully qualified path, or it could just be `msiexec.exe`, which is found thanks to the PATH environment variable. However, I would like to validate the path and provide a meaningful logged error when the `-FilePath` isn't found.

Problem is, `Test-Path` doesn't search with the PATH environment variable, so as it is now when using `msiexec.exe` `Test-Path` always fails. Now, I could test to see if the provided path has a parent, and if not read the PATH environment variable, split it up and loop through it. But, I wonder if there is a trick to do this already?

I have already tried `Resolve-Path`, but that is about resolving relative paths, not unrolling the PATH env var.

So, is there a native way to do this, or is my only option to roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to try and find the command

```
Get-Command msiexec.exe
```

Comment: Aha, EXACTLY what I figured PowerShell could do, if I only knew how. ;) I had Get-Command in the back of my head, but for some reason I was thinking it would return the PS1 file where a CommandLet was defined. Thanks.